# Great Baikal Trail from Listvyanka to Bol'shiye Koty

Tags: russia, irkutsk, baikal

It says on the Great Baikal Trail's website that a permit is necessary to take the hike from Listvyanka to Bol'shiye Koty.

However, I have not been able to find the following details on the website:

- When is their Listvyanka office open? (in case my email to them isn't processed)
- Is there a possibility that the permit won't be granted? Are there any requirements or general things to know? (not for the hike itself, but for the permit)

Comment: I can't comment on the permit process, but having visited both ends of the trail last month, I can tell you that there is zero enforcement of the "requirement".

Comment: See also [Outdoors.SE] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[2GIS claims](https://2gis.ru/irkutsk/firm/70000001025211146?queryState=center%2F104.87087%2C51.84843%2Fzoom%2F17) that Listvyanka office is open daily at `9:00–18:00` with dinner break at `13:00–13:48` (for some reason).

As for not granting the permit, from [their page](https://greatbaikaltrail.org/tropi/listvyanka-bol-shie-koty/) I don't see why they won't, provided that the trail is open at all.

There are also reports that you can [get this permit](https://www.irk.ru/tourism/club/article/65519/) by e-mail: t@baikal-1.ru.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I emailed them, but apparently they only give permits on the same day or the day before.